# Angular 4 Site using http://sitename.com?id=a removing the ?id=a from URL

Tags: angular

Angular 4 Site
using in browser http://127.0.0.1:4200/?id=a removing the ?id=a from URL and browser showing http://127.0.0.1:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Ffm and also i am not getting the query parameter in my app.component.

if i use http://127.0.0.1:4200/index.html?id=a then  its making it http://sitename.com

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'index.html' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'index.html'
>       at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError
>   (router.es5.js:1356)

My App.component as below:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams =>{
  debugger
  console.log(queryParams['code']);
});
```

my route looks like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'is',
    component: ISComponent,
    children: [], canActivate: [AuthGuard]

  },
  {
    path: 'ca',
    component: CAComponent,
    children: [], canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'fm',
    component: FMComponent,
    children: [], canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/fm', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

As the url http://127.0.0.1:4200/index.html?id=a will be from other area its forming. there is no any other way to pass data rather then query parameter

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Assuming you are using the angular cli, the cli serves your `index.html` file for all routes. At this point angular takes over the routing and changes the url as needed. So you do not need to load `127.0.0.1:4200/index.html`, just `127.0.0.1:4200`. This is why you are getting `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'` Angular is looking for a route that has a path of `index.html`. To load your routes, append the path to the end of your url `127.0.0.1:4200/is`, `127.0.0.1:4200/ca`, `127.0.0.1:4200/fm`, etc...

Comment: @LLai If you read my question i already using without index.html also, but the query parameter is removing after i run it on the browser.