# Cannot match any routes if index.html contain query params

Tags: angular

When i open [localhost:4000/index.html](http://localhost:4000/index.html), i get redirected to the HomeComponent, which is the correct behaviour.

But by adding query params like [localhost:4000/index.html?foo=bar](http://localhost:4000/index.html?foo=bar), i got following error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'

Opening [localhost:4000/?foo=bar](http://localhost:4000/?foo=bar) work's fine.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I already read the answer from @LLai on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376179/angular-4-site-using-http-sitename-comid-a-removing-the-id-a-from-url), but is there are a way to add query params on the index.html?

And how exactly does the query params influence the routing behaviour on Angular, so the index.html can't found anymore?

Thank you

Comment: why you want to run like this ? index.html?q=foo

Comment: You just have no route for 'index.html'

Comment: Why you are trying to reach index.html directly? In Angular architecture index.html is assigned to call JS files which is rendering your Angular application. It will work when you define a route with index path.

Comment: @aviboy2006 I could run it without index.html, but i want to understand why the routing don't work anymore if i add query params to the index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could run it without index.html, but i want to understand why the routing don't work anymore if i add query params to the index.html

Then you probably want to dig deep into angular-cli code (to see how the app is hosted) and routing module (to see how the routes are resolved).

I have never actually done this myself, but my educated guess would be that `index.html` is a special case, that is always resolved as base href. If you use any path other than `index.html` (e.g. adding params) it will be used to resolve the routing that you have declared within your application.

Note that files declared as assets in your `angular.json` file will take precedence over the routing, so the file will be served instead of using sub-path as a routing path.

As stated above, this is an educated guess - if you doubts, diving into the code head-first would be your best bet.